# How to write a csv dictionary in a loop?

Tags: python, csv, io

There are lot of questions about how to write a csv in a loop, but my problem is similar but different:

What i want:

- I want to write a dictionary into a csv file continuously in a loop
- at beginning it should make a header
- then in every loop it should write the results into this csv file as a new row
- Because i have over 10.000 files, I abort the program every time after some iteration and want the possibility to read the csv file

```py
import csv

def main(file):
    output=open('output.csv', mode='a', newline='')
    fieldnames = ['filename', 'speed','lane','coordinates']
    output_writer = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=';', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    output_writer.writeheader()

    for file_name in file:
        coordinates=.... #myprogramm
        for i_result in range(len(coordinates)):
            speed=... #my programm #filetype: int
            coordinates=... #my programm #filetype: dictionairy
            lane= #my programm #filetype: int or None
            output_writer.writerow({"filename": file_name, "speed": speed, "lane": str(lane), 'coordinates': coordinates[i_result]})
    output.close()
```

Also i tried

```py
with open('output.csv', mode='a', newline='') as output:
```

And
Also I tried `mode ="w"`

But it gives me an file with multiple times the heading back. I am confused because the header is outside the loop

Comment: What you want to do is probably easy. The problem is that your text speaks of many files in a loop and multiple times the heading, while your code writes the header only once outside of the only loop. So I cannot understand what you are really trying to do. Please have your code and your text say the same thing...

Comment: Puuh thanks for your answer. my text and my code are trying to say the same thing, but maybe its not obvious:
what i want:
- to write a csv file
-at beginning 1x the heading
-then for every loop the results of this loop into the csv file as a new row

But actually it only writes the header multiple times (im confused too because its outside the loop)

Comment: After each `output_writer.writerow()` call, add one to `output.flush()`.

Comment: works perfect! thanks!!!!